# Usuário Oracle é uma palavra reservada, pode gerar problemas ?

Tags: oracle

Pode haver algum problema se um usuário Oracle (USER) é uma palavra reservada ?

No caso : MAX

Answer (score 2):

Sim!

Já estive nessa mesma situação, porém, no MySQL.

Você deverá usar aspas "MAX" para informar como uma palavra normal.

veja neste [link](http://www.profissionaloracle.com.br/gpo/artigo/banco-de-dados/151-trabalhando-com-palavras-reservadas-no-banco-de-dados-oracle) e procure por MAX ou por RESERVED WORDS (PL/SQL)

Espero ter te ajudado!

Comment: Vou trocar o nome do user, não vou esquentar com isto não, valeu.

Comment: É válido, veja se isso não afeta outros procedimentos, functions e views que você possa já ter criado!

Comment: Não, é um sistema antigo que usa o user Oracle para autenticar no Sistema , "dropo" um e crio outro com o sobrenome do usuário. Só queria confirmar se podia ser isto.

Comment: De fato era isto , com outro user funcionou.

Comment: Com as aspas o usuário é identificado mais fácil! Não querendo me meter (curiosidade), que tipo de sistema é esse? Automação Comercial? Folha de Pagamento? Contabilidade? Livro Caixa? :)

Comment: Um Sistema legado, não temos os fontes.